# Responsive image solution

Tags: javascript, image

I just made this responsive image solution, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve. Use cases can be found at http://responsimage.com/.

```
/* responsimage.com v0.2.3 */
(function ($, window, Date) {

    'use strict';

    $(function() {

        var rPrefs = $('meta[name="responsimage"]'),
            rServer = rPrefs.data('server'),
            rStatic = rPrefs.data('static') || 'http://f.cl.ly/items/0M3H0q3n1Z1S1y362d09/spacer.gif',
            rLoading = rPrefs.data('loading') || 'http://f.cl.ly/items/2w2G3N2p0B400Z380J1u/loading.gif',
            rLimit = rPrefs.data('limit') || 100,
            rTimestamp = new Date(),
            rTags = $('[data-responsimage]');

        function responsimage(rInit) {
            rTags.each(function() {
                var rThis = $(this),
                    filename = rThis.data('responsimage'),
                    rWidth = rThis.width(),
                    rHeight = rThis.height(),
                    rAnchor = rThis.data('responsimage-anchor') || 5,
                    rImage;

                if(rInit) {
                    rThis.attr('src', rStatic).css('background', '#fff url(' + rLoading + ') no-repeat center');
                }

                if(rThis.css('font-family') === 'pixel-ratio-2') {
                    rWidth *= 2;
                    rHeight *= 2;
                }

                rImage = rServer.replace('width', rWidth).replace('height', rHeight).replace('anchor', rAnchor).replace('filename', filename);

                if(filename !== 'disabled') {
                    rThis.attr('src', rImage);
                }
            });
        }

        responsimage(1);

        $(window).resize(function () {
            var rNow = new Date();

            if (rNow - rTimestamp >= rLimit) {
                responsimage(false);
            }
        });

        window.onorientationchange = function() {      
            setTimeout(responsimage, 0); 
        };
    });
}(jQuery, window, Date));
```

Comment: please put code in question

Comment: Do you start all your variables with `r` for the lulz?

Comment: jQuery dependency = not efficient.

Comment: I started with `r` so I would ensure no conflicts

Comment: So you _do_ start all your variables with `r` for the lulz. Good stuff o/

Comment: I dont understand

Answer (score 2):

1. declare the variables inside "rTags.each()" on the outside.  This way there not being declared on each iteration.
2. The naming of parameters "window" and "Date". I would suggest naming them something different to avoid confusion. This way you can distinguish between the globals from the parameters.
3. Since you variables are scoped in the functions you can drop the "r" if you wanted too.